AWS RolesAnywhere use within Azure Pipeline
Experiencing the following error within my pipeline:
[Error: not finding developer profile in the aws config]
This error occurs in the following step:

script: |
aws sts get-caller-identity --profile developer
displayName: Retrieve Profile Credentials

The step before builds successfully:

script: |
echo [profile developer] > C:\Users\VssAdministrator.aws\config
echo credential_process =
"C:\Users\ProgramFiles\aws_signing_helper.exe" credential-process
--certificate $(certificate.pem)
--private-key $(private-key.pem)
--trust-anchor-arn $(trustAnchorArn)
--profile-arn $(profileArn)
--role-arn $(roleArn)
--region $(awsRegion)



C:\Users\VssAdministrator.aws\config


echo region = $(awsRegion) >> C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.aws\config
echo output = json >> C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.aws\config
set AWS_PROFILE=developer
aws configure list-profiles

displayName: 'Configure AWS CLI Profile'
